# facebook publish_action default public

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a php script that post content users choose to post to their facebook timeline but I want to default the post the users post to their timeline public unless they change it... how do I go by doing that I am using the oldest facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the
>   one granted

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#pubfields

In other words, it is not possible if the user did not choose "public" when he installed your App.